# How do I write an SQL query that gives me the amount of times a value is repeated in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

So I have two tables which I have created:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Advertising_Campaign` (
 `CampaignID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 `AdvertName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `ProjectLead` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
 `CostEstimate` decimal NULL,
 `CampaignCost` decimal NULL,
 `EndDateEst` date NULL,
 `StartDate` date NULL,
 `EndDate` date NULL,
 `Theme` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `AdvertType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CampaignID`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff_works_campaign` (
`CampaignID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`StaffID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`SalaryGrade` Integer NOT NULL,
`isSup` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`, `CampaignID`), 
CONSTRAINT `FK_StaffID3` FOREIGN KEY (`StaffID`) REFERENCES `Staff` (`StaffID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CampaignID2` FOREIGN KEY (`CampaignID`) REFERENCES `Advertising_Campaign` (`CampaignID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

which gives the tables:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Basically, I want to write a query that will return me a list of the advertising_campaign.AdvertName with more than 2 staff members working on them and a count of the number of staff members whose staff_works_campaign.SalaryGrade is greater than 2.

I have tried:

```
select a.advertname, count(*) as 'Greater Than 2'
from advertising_campaign a inner join staff_works_campaign
where staff_works_campaign.SalaryGrade > 2;
```

Which isn't exactly what I want, it returns:

[image]

I am a bit unsure at what this is returning exactly because I would thought it would have returned a count of 2(because of the fact that there are 2 entries with a SalaryGrade of 4 in the table), might be because of the way inner join works?

I am also a bit confused as to how to filter for 'more than 2 staff members', My idea is to see the amount of times the staff_works_campaign.CampaignID has appeared in the staff_works_campaign table to see how many staff members are apart of the same campaign.

I'm not sure how to structure it to count the amount of times campaignID is repeated and to return the names of the adverts that have a campaignID that has 2 or more staff members working on it.

So in this case I would want it to return a table with AdvertName of only those campaigns with two or more people working on them and a count of those staff members who have a salary grade greater than 2.

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be easier to read, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need a condition to join the two tables on. Secondly you can use a `Group By` and `Having` clause to put the filter on aggregation. Finally you need to count the number of staff with a salary grade > 2, which you can `SUM` a conditional for. Something like this:

```
select a.advertname, Sum(CASE WHEN c.SalaryGrade > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Greater Than 2'
from advertising_campaign a inner join staff_works_campaign c
    on a.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
Group By a.advertname Having count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    a.CampaignID
    ,a.AdvertName
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT s.StaffID) AS [Count of staff]
    ,SUM(
        --Use this to get a total of the staff who are 
        --in a SalaryGrade greater than 2
        CASE WHEN s.SalaryGrade > 2
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 --anyone who is under this level will be a 0 and not count
        END
    ) as [Count of staff above salary grade]
FROM 
    advertising_campaign AS a 
    INNER JOIN staff_works_campaign AS s
        --dont forget the join condition
        ON a.CampaignID = s.CampaignID
--Dont want a where here, we want to include ALL staff.
--WHERE 
--  staff_works_campaign.SalaryGrade > 2
GROUP BY
    a.CampaignID
    ,a.AdvertName
HAVING
    --more than two members of staff working on the same campaign.
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.StaffID) > 2
```

Comment: The AdvertName does not have `UNIQUE` constraint so this query might give little bit surprising results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following if you want both conditions together, 
2 people working on camp, whose salary_grade >2

```
SELECT AdvertName 
FROM Advertising_Campaign 
WHERE CampaignID IN 
 ( 
   SELECT 
     CampaignID 
   FROM 
     staff_works_campaign 
   WHERE 
     SalaryGrade > 2 
   GROUP BY 
     CampaignID 
   HAVING 
   COUNT(DISTINCT StaffID) >= 2
)
```

Comment: You don't need the COUNT(DISTINCT) as there can't be same StaffID for one CampaignID because of primary key definition: `PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, CampaignID)`

Comment: Thanks, this was the most simple and easy to understand answer with my current knowledge :).

Answer (score 1):

What you have received as a result from your query is the count of **all** staff members across all campaigns that have a salary grade greater than 2. It returns "Star Wars 3" as the advert name simply because it's the first name it came across in all the results that the COUNT operates over. (Some other SQL technologies such as Microsoft SQL Server actually won't allow you to do this kind of query to avoid this confusion.)

In order to get the results to be split by the campaign, you have to use the `GROUP BY` clause as suggested in the other answers. This will tell SQL to calculate any aggregate functions (i.e. COUNT) over groups of records that all match for one or more fields. In your case, you want to group by the campaignID, since you want the COUNT to be calculated for each campaign individually. You could do this on the advert name as well, but better to do it on the ID in case you have two with the same name. Modifying your query to do that, we get:

```
select a.campaignID, count(*) as 'Greater Than 2'
from advertising_campaign a inner join staff_works_campaign
where staff_works_campaign.SalaryGrade > 2
group by a.campaignID;
```

This still isn't quite going to work though, because the salary grade condition is applied before the COUNT. We need to move that part out into a new query that wraps around this one. We also need to limit the campaigns down to those with two staff - thankfully, we don't need yet another outer query for that. The HAVING keyword allows a condition to be applied after a GROUP BY, so we can do:

```
select a.campaignID, count(*) as 'staff_amount'
from advertising_campaign a inner join staff_works_campaign
group by a.campaignID
having staff_amount > 2;
```

Now, adding the staff salary condition and another select from advertising_campaign to get the advert name in an outer query, we finally get:

```
select advertising_campaign.advertname
from advertising_campaign
inner join staff_works_campaign on advertising_campaign.campaignid = staff_works_campaign.campaignid
inner join
(
    select a.campaignID, count(*) as 'staff_amount'
    from advertising_campaign a inner join staff_works_campaign
    group by a.campaignID
    having staff_amount > 2
) large_campaigns on advertising_campaign.campaignid = large_campaigns.campaignid
where staff_works_campaign.salarygrade > 2
```